# Can sklearn preprocessing.LabelEncoder or DataFrameMapper support pandas get_chunk?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a **big csv** file,so that I used pandas **get_chunk()** function to get dataFrame in each loop.
And I used LabelEncoder() in every loop,But I found that labels are **not globally uniform.**

CODES

```
# coding: utf-8
  import pandas as pd
  from sklearn import preprocessing

  input_data1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep='^', header=0, encoding='utf-8', 
    error_bad_lines=False, iterator=True,
                      low_memory=False)
  le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
  loop = True
  number = 1
  while loop:
    try:
       print 'first ', number, ' loop'
       df = input_data1.get_chunk(2)


       sd = le.fit(df['title_a'])
       print list(le.classes_)
       # list(le.classes_)
       print le.transform(df['title_a'])
       mapping = dict(zip(le.classes_, range(len(le.classes_))))

       print mapping
       print list(le.inverse_transform([1, 1, 0]))

   except StopIteration:
       loop = False
       print "Iteration is stopped."
   number = number + 1
```

here are data in csv:

```
title_a^title_b^title_c
a^b^c
aa^bb^cc
aaa^bbb^ccc
aaaa^bbbb^cccc
```

map in first loop:
    `{u'a': 0, u'aa': 1}`

map in second loop:
    `{u'aaaa': 1, u'aaa': 0}`

'a' and 'aaa' have the same key or value(key or value does not matter),
The problem is that each loop has its own map.

Any advises or suggestions or API?
Thank you.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you make the label encoder outside the loop and call `transform` on each chunk?

Comment: No,it doesn't work. Also not Global unity

Comment: You'd be better off just reading in `title_a`, drop the duplicates and encode it and then merge the results back

Comment: In practice the ’title_a‘ column may be very large...In order to prevent OOM so use the get_chunk()

Comment: I think you will need to maintain some sort of global dict here unfortunately, I did a test and the LabelEncoder state gets cleared every time you call `fit` which is why it resets the encoding for each chunk. Personally I'd just load just title_a, drop the duplicates and append these to a list so it makes a list of dfs, `concat` these vertically, call `drop_duplicates` again on the final df to reduce the df size, `encode` and then merge back. If the concatenated dfs you could also filter out from each chunk any labels already seen

Comment: Thank you for your sugesstion, I think i can maintain a map file by myself.And use `{k: v for v, k in enumerate(df[column].unique())}` instead of LabelEncoder ,so that I can read my map file in every loop,handle by myself